# ¿Como puedo obtener la url de una imagen en liquid? (shopify)

Tags: html, liquid, shopify

Estoy intentando hacer una sección personalizada pero no hallo la forma de obtener la url de la imagen seleccionada desde mi image_picker, puedo seleccionar la imagen pero al parecer el codigo de mi sección recibe una url vacia

aqui esta el bloque de css donde estoy intentando ponerla

```
  .banner-dl-home{
    
    background-image: url('{{  settings.url2 | img_url: '2048x'   }}');
}
```

y el esquema JSON para esta parte, la cual no esta en un bloque sino directamente dentro de la sección "settings"

```
{

  "id": "url2",
  "type": "image_picker",
  "label": "Inserte  su imagen de fondo"
}
```

pero no obtiene la url
intente poner la url en una etiqueta `<p>` pero esto es lo que obtengo

[image: //cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/shopify/assets/no-image-2048-5e88c1b20e087fb7bbe9a3771824e743c244f437e4f8ba93bbf7b11b53f7824c_300x300.gif]

Comment: Bro... You are in terreno de habla hispana... Traduce tu pregunta porfavor

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que especificar el tamaño de la imagen que va a traer shopify y te falta el atributo section, así seria:

```css
 .banner-dl-home{

background-image: url('{{ section.settings.url2 | img_url: '800x' }}');
}
```